# Pass a PORO from view to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What would be the best way to pass a Plain Old Ruby Object that I have in a view to a controller method?

It is not an object that is persisted in the DB. I would rather not refactor things and just want some ideas on best way to pass this object.

**view**

```
link_to "activate", activate_apis_path(my_ip_instance: @my_ip), class: "btn btn-primary btn-xs"
```

**controller**

```
@my_ip = params[:my_ip_instance]
```

`@my_ip` is just a string... want the whole object

**(Rails 4.2)**

Answer (score 3):

Usually the best way is through a form. Consider creating a form with hidden fields for all of your `@my_ip` attributes.

```
<%= form_tag activate_apis_path do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "my_ip_instance[foo]", @my_ip.foo %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "my_ip_instance[tomato]", @my_ip.tomato %>
  <%= submit_tag "Activate", class: "btn btn-primary btn-xs" %>
<% end %>
```

(Extra credit: you could also loop over `@my_ip`'s attributes to generate the hidden fields.)

Another way is to serialize `@my_ip` as JSON and then deserialize it in the controller. I think that is much messier though.

```
link_to "activate", activate_apis_path(my_ip_instance: @my_ip.to_json)
```

To make this work for a more complex object, you would need to write your own serializer/deserializer logic into the class as described in [this post](http://www.skorks.com/2010/04/serializing-and-deserializing-objects-with-ruby/).

```
require "json"

class A
  def initialize(string, number)
    @string = string
    @number = number
  end

  def to_json(*a)
    {
      "json_class"   => self.class.name,
      "data"         => {"string" => @string, "number" => @number }
    }.to_json(*a)
  end

  def self.json_create(o)
    new(o["data"]["string"], o["data"]["number"])
  end
end
```

Comment: The object is very complex. Can not create a form to represent it. I see the view code to pass @my_ip. What would you put in the controller to instantiate that same object?

Comment: I would recommend reading this post to see how they handle the `to_json` and `json_create` scenarios. http://www.skorks.com/2010/04/serializing-and-deserializing-objects-with-ruby/

Comment: How did you initialize the object to start with?

Comment: It is initialized like a PORO. I just want to pass it around.

Comment: I would initialize it - if its not a REST resource don't pass it through HTTP. You are just opening up a bunch of potential security holes.

Comment: If initializing the object is expensive (if it for example has to get something from an external API) use memcached or redis to cache it.

Comment: @max is giving good advice, but it really depends on your situation. I'm afraid it'll be hard to help much further unless you update your question to include very specific information. For one thing, it's hard to answer a question assuming a simple object and then receive a comment stating that it's a complex object. Help us help you!

Comment: its an internal tool that I am developing. Security is not an issue. I just can't believe I can't pass a Ruby object in a view to a controller. Good or bad... I just can't believe it is a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

What you basically need to do is to serialize the object. Rails provides built in options to serialize objects and `Object.to_query` which can be used to convert to query parameters.

**But**, passing around a bunch of state like that violates rest and is indicative of a poor application design. If it's a non-persisted object it should be passed as form parameters in a POST/PATCH request. In a GET request you should strive to initialize all objects needed from  the headers, params from the request url and session.